# I've made a google apps script I want to share within my own domain but not publish to the web?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-apps-script-addon

I've made a Google Apps Script project in one sheet that I want to easily access from multiple other Google Sheets, in Google Drive as well as Team Drive.

It would make no sense to publish this script to the Google Web Store since the functionality is based on our own files.

Can I publish it as an addon that's only accessible for users of my domain?

Comment: You might be able to use it from a library.[Library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible by listing it as 'private' in the Developer Dashboard. In the script editor, go to *Publish > Deploy as add-on*. You have to follow the steps necessary to access the Developer Dashboard and create your listing.

Fill in all the details of your app (name, description, icon etc.) and set its visibility options at the bottom.

[image: Visibility options]